Does Covariance work if you only center one of the variables?
By definition, Covariance is $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y) = E \left[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])\right]$.
However, I was looking at Philippe Rigollet's EDX course (MIT Micromasters), and at one point he mentioned that you can get away with only centering one of them, i.e.
$\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y) = E \left[X(Y-E[Y])\right] = E \left[(X-E[X])Y\right]$
Is this the case? I have searched but am unable to find a proof.
By some simulation, the property does seem to hold:
import numpy as np
x_high_corr = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y_high_corr = 2 * np.linspace(0, 10, 100) + 5 + np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)  # Adding some noise

## Check values upto 6th digit
assert (
    (x_high_corr - x_high_corr.mean())*(y_high_corr - y_high_corr.mean())
).mean().round(6) == (
    (x_high_corr)*(y_high_corr - y_high_corr.mean())
).mean().round(6) == (
    (x_high_corr - x_high_corr.mean())*(y_high_corr)
).mean().round(6)  
```


$\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}$
Note that $\Cov(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$. Then using linearity of expectation,
$$\mathbb{E}[X(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])]=\mathbb{E}[XY-X\mathbb{E}[Y]]=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[Y]]=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=\Cov(X,Y)$$

If you center just $Y$, and not $X$, then you're omitting the quantity
$$E\left[ -E(X) (Y-E(Y))\right]$$
from the calculation. But this quantity can be simplified by factoring out the constant $-E(X)$:
$$-E(X)\cdot \underbrace{E\left[Y-(EY)\right]}_0$$
